# Can I add a nullable column to MSSQL database without updating Entity

Tags: entity-framework

I need to add a nullable column to a database without breaking other EF users of the database. Will I break them?

Comment: If it's code first you can.

Comment: It is code first, the change is pending deploy to our test environment now, I'll come back with the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested this with Code First. If you add a **Nullable** column to the database, EF Code First consumers will not have an issue working with the table.